# Flexibility for a code to generate baum hierarchy for a given CSV file

Tags: php, laravel, csv, recursion, hierarchy

I need to convert CSV file's content into an hierarchy for my website with the help of [Baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum) Library for Hierarchy generation...

Below is the format for CSV file which user will upload for parsing into Baum Hierarchy. Columns in it represents level of hierarchy.
[CSV File Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGFQE.jpg)

Now i have parsed this CSV file into 2 dimensional array ( `$companyDetailsIn2dArray` ) and the code i have wrote supports generation till 3rd level only and i want it to be "flexible for any level" i.e. for levels more than 3. Now to do so, with the code, i have wrote encourages me to write recursion function for it but i am confused, from where should i begin this. Temporary variables(`$lastDeptNodeI; $lastDeptNodeJ; $lastMacNodeI; $lastMacNodeJ`) that i have used for storing last created nodes limits me to write recursion function...

Please help me writing recursion function or suggest me any other way to obtain Baum Hierarchy with CSV file...

Following is my code...

```
$lastDeptNodeI =-1; //variable used to store array location(row) for last created 1st level node i.e. Dept node
$lastDeptNodeJ =-1; //variable used to store array location(column) for last created 1st level node i.e. Dept node
$lastMacNodeI =-1; //variable used to store array location(row) for last created 2nd level node i.e. Machine node
$lastMacNodeJ =-1; //variable used to store array location(column) for last created 2nd level node i.e. Machine node
$root = Company::create(['name' => $newCompanyName]);   //Creating node
$root->makeRoot();  //Making Root Node
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($companyDetailsIn2dArray);$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($companyDetailsIn2dArray[$i]);$j++){
        if($companyDetailsIn2dArray[$i][$j] != "") {
            if ($j == 0) {  //if it is Dept!
                $newNode[$i][$j] = Company::create(['name' => $companyDetailsIn2dArray[$i]{$j}]);
                $newNode[$i][$j]->makeChildOf($root);
                $lastDeptNodeI = $i;
                $lastDeptNodeJ = $j;
                $lastMacNodeI = -1;
                $lastMacNodeJ = -1;
            } elseif ($j == 1) { // if it is machine
                $newNode[$i][$j] = Company::create(['name' => $companyDetailsIn2dArray[$i]{$j}]);
                if($lastDeptNodeI!=-1 || $lastDeptNodeJ!=-1) {
                    $newNode[$i][$j]->makeChildOf($newNode[$lastDeptNodeI][$lastDeptNodeJ]);
                    $lastMacNodeI = $i;
                    $lastMacNodeJ = $j;
                }
                else{
                    $newNode[$i][$j]->makeChildOf($root);
                    $lastMacNodeI = $i;
                    $lastMacNodeJ = $j;
                }
            } elseif ($j == 2)
            { //if it is Meter!
                $newNode[$i][$j] = Company::create(['name' => $companyDetailsIn2dArray[$i]{$j}]);
                if($lastMacNodeI!=-1 || $lastMacNodeJ!=-1){
                    $newNode[$i][$j]->makeChildOf($newNode[$lastMacNodeI][$lastMacNodeJ]);
                }
                elseif($lastDeptNodeI!=-1 || $lastDeptNodeJ!=-1){
                    $newNode[$i][$j]->makeChildOf($newNode[$lastDeptNodeI][$lastDeptNodeJ]);
                    $lastMacNodeI = $i;
                    $lastMacNodeJ = $j;
                }
                else{
                    $newNode[$i][$j]->makeChildOf($root);
                    $lastDeptNodeI = $i;
                    $lastDeptNodeJ = $j;
                    $lastMacNodeI = -1;
                    $lastMacNodeJ = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "File parsed Successfully!";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could add the nodes in a depth-first search kind of way, when you find a node add the children as well.

If you want to go full recursive you will need 2 recursive functions:

1. The first would be the function that adds a node to your tree, but
   after adding a node it would find all of its child (1 level down)
   nodes, and call itself for those.

The signature of this function could look something like this: addNode(parent_node, i_of_current_node, j_of_current_node, content_of_current_node)

The recursion ends when there are no children.

I'd write a helper function to find the children of a node too. You just look for the next nonempty cell with the same j as j_of_current_node, and get the non empty cells from j_of_current_node + 1 between i_of_current_node and i_of_next_node.

2. The second recursive function would read the companyDetailsIn2dArray
   column by column.

The signature of this function could be something like:
readColumn(j_of_current_column, i_of_first_node_in_prev_column)

The recursion ends when j_of_current_column is larger then the size of your array.

---

As you read a column, you call your addNode function for every none empty cell like this: addNode($root, $i, $j, $companyDetailsIn2dArray[$i][$j])
The addNode creates the new node under root, finds the children, then calls itself for the child nodes like addNode($newNode, $childI, $childJ, $companyDetailsIn2dArray[$childI][$childJ]).

This way, once you read the first column you have added every node in the file under the $i of the first nonempty cell in the first column. You process the first column by calling readColumn(0, i_size_of_array)

When processing any subsequent columns (the same way as the first) you only read it until you reach the i of the first nonempty cell in the previous column, because you have already added nodes with higher i index as those had a parent in the previous column. You process the columns after the first by calling readColumn(j_of_current_column + 1, i_of_first_node_in_current_column).

Comment: Thanks Attila Repasi... Didn't went for full recursive.. but on your paths... Thanks again :)